# Encode multiple discrete vectors into one number

Tags: python, math, tree

Given n vectors each in the set of integers a to i (i1 can be different from i2 can be different from in), and given the value of each vector, how can you create a single integer to represent this state. And how can you make a function to put this number back into it's vector form. I know this problem can be represented using a tree, but I'm struggling to create the function for it.

For Example:
[image]
In this image, there are 3 vectors, and `i = [3, 3, 2]`

If the input is `[0, 2, 0]` it would return `4`, and an input of`[2, 2, 0]` would return `16`, where each number is how it traverses the tree.

Thanks!

Edit: Spelling

Edit 2: Clarifying the example

Comment: You could represent this tree as a multi-dimensional array (achieved using nested lists). The shape of this array will be based on our `i`, and populate the leaves (innermost nested elements) with the integers like you did in the diagram. To get the vector back from some integer `x` perform a DFS like search over this n-D array to find `x` and note down the indices in each dimension of the n-D array.

Comment: "In this image, there are 3 vectors, and i = [3, 3, 2]" I can't understand. I don't see any vectors in the image; I only see some numbers that are connected with lines that I assume are intended to represent a tree data structure. What is the underlying logical rule? What is `i` (why choose that name, and what does the thing named `i` *mean*?), and why should it be equal to `[3, 3, 2]`, and what does that have to do with the diagram?

Comment: "how can you create a single integer to represent this state." Why should it be possible to do so? Then, what should the integer be for this input? Actually - *what is the input* here? Should the list `[3, 3, 2]` be the input, and there is some particular integer you should get as output? What integer? "If the combination is [0, 2, 0] it would return 4, but [2, 2, 0] would return 16." By "the combination", do you mean the *input*? (Then why not say so?) Why should those be the `return` values?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "what does the thing named i mean" - each element of i represents the max int of that vector, which is why for the tree the number of branches from each node is equal to the corresponding element of i. 
"why should it be possible to do so" - proven possibke because the problem is able to be represented using a tree, with each node of the final layer numbered
"By " combination, do you mean the input?" - yes, changed the wording in the question
"Why should those be the return values? " - If you trace through the tree using the input as the path, that is the number you reach

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix

Comment: Ah, so let me see if I understand this properly. The idea is that, because `i` (which is **not** the input) is equal to [3, 3, 2], you want to *conceptually* draw out a tree with 3, 3 and 2 nodes at the three levels; and then the result for `[2, 2, 0]` is `16` because that is the number you get by navigating the tree, choosing child `[2]`, then child `[2]`, then child `[0]`? I had to think really hard to understand what you meant, and I'm not even sure I would have come up with that idea without @PresidentJamesK.Polk's link.

Comment: Anyway, you should not have to build any actual data structure to solve this problem. If you check that link, you should see that there is a simple mathematical rule that gives you the result. For example, we can compute the result for `[2, 2, 0]` by doing `2` (from the input) `* 3 * 2` (product of every value in `i` *except* the first, which isn't actually useful except for *validating* the input) to get `12`; then adding `2` (from the second value in the input) `* 2` (every value in `i` except the first two) to get `4`, etc. for each level of the tree. Then we sum `12 + 4 + 0 = 16`.

Comment: Do you understand why this works? If not, then you actually purely have a math question, not a programming question, and should try https://math.stackexchange.com instead. If you do, please try to write the code for it, then ask a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using itsreddy's meathod

```py
import numpy as np


def generate_nested_arr(layers: list, number):
    if len(layers) == 1:
        return np.array(list(range(number, number + layers[0]))), number + layers[0]
    arr = []
    for _ in range(layers[0]):
        a, number = generate_nested_arr(layers[1:], number)
        arr.append(a)
    return np.array(arr), number


def encode_to_number(path, maxes):
    assert len(path) == len(maxes)
    arr, _ = generate_nested_arr(maxes, 0)
    ans = arr
    for i in path:
        ans = ans[i]
    return ans


def decode_from_number(key, maxes):
    arr, _ = generate_nested_arr(maxes, 0)
    return np.array(np.where(arr == key)).flatten()
```